# valueForKey not working within for loop in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, key-value-coding

In my class I have below method which returns an array of names of all properties in it:

```
func getListOfProperties() -> Array<Any>
    {
        var count : UInt32 = 0
        let classToInspect = NSURL.self
        let properties : UnsafePointer <objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(classToInspect, &count)
        var propertyNames : Array<String> = []
        let intCount = Int(count)
        for var i = 0; i < intCount; i++ {
            let property : objc_property_t = properties[i]
            let properyName = NSString(UTF8String: property_getName(property))
            propertyNames += properyName
        }
        free(properties)
        return propertyNames
    }
```

I have one more method in which I am trying to manipulate these properties using valueForKey, within a for loop:

```
func doSomethingWithPropertyName()
    {
        var someProperty = self.valueForKey("someProperty") // this is fine for compiler :-)

        var properties = self.getListOfProperties()
        for (index, propertyName) in enumerate(properties)
        {
            var currentProperty = self.valueForKey(propertyName) // compiler complains : 'protocol <>' is not convertible to 'String':-(

        }
    }
```

Problem is -

> if I try to access a property using valueForKey within for loop,
>   compiler complains - protocol <>' is not convertible to 'String'

**Note:** If I try to do the same thing outside the for loop it works fine.

Any clues?

Comment: try `as NSString`. and [key-value-coding] have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Why did you use `Any` instead of `String`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that propertyName is defined as an `Any`. There is no implicit casting in Swift.

You either have to cast propertyName to a String:

```
for (index, propertyName) in enumerate(properties) {
    if let stringPropertyName = propertyName as? String {
        var currentProperty = self.valueForKey(stringPropertyName)
    }
}
```

or you can have your `getListOfProperties` method return a string array:

```
func getListOfProperties() -> Array<String>
```